# R use values in vector to become name of dataframe

Tags: r, lapply, rmysql

I am getting the names of tables from a database and I want to select all the data from each table and create a dataframe automatically. The code

```
nm = dbListTables(connection)
```

creates a vector like:

```
[1] "Account"                          "Credit__Amortization_Payment__c" 
[3] "Credit__Amortization_Schedule__c" "Credit__Loan_Payment__c"         
[5] "Credit__Loan__c"
```

As an example,

```
 nm = c("Account", "Credit__Amortization_Payment__c", "Credit__Amortization_Schedule__c", "Credit__Loan_Payment__c", "Credit__Loan__c")
```

I create a list of a query for each value in a loop:

```
qry <- list()
for (i in 1:length(nm)) {
  qry[i] <- paste0("select * from ", nm[i])
  }
```

Then I can't figure out how to save the name of the data frame as the values from the vector, so I have to manually type it out like this, but I would like to just loop through it saving a data frame with exactly the same name and structure from the list nm.

```
q = paste0(qry[1])
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, q)
Account <- dbFetch(rs, n=-1)
```

I repeat it here for each value in the vector manually but I would like to do this automatically based on the values in nm = dbListTables(connection)

```
q = paste0(qry[3])
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, q)
Credit__Amortization_Schedule__c <- dbFetch(rs, n=-1)
```

Comment: I would like the dataframe to be named like nm[i] nm[1] = Account, nm[3] = Credit__Amortization_Schedule__c

Comment: have a look at `?setNames`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `assign` is what you are looking for, e.g.

```
> assign("x", 5)
> x
[1] 5
```

In your case e.g. for query 1

```
q <- paste0(qry[1])
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, q)
assign(nm[1], dbFetch(rs, n=-1))
```

should work. Also have a look at the [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).

Comment: That works great.  I just could not ask the question correctly to find the way to find assign.  Now everything works in one loop:     for (i in 1:length(nm)) {
  qry[i] <- paste0("select * from ", nm[i])
  q = paste0(qry[i])
  rs <- dbSendQuery(con, q)
  assign(nm[i], dbFetch(rs, n=-1))
}